# Every time I try to filter dataframe by string values, my dataframe is empty. But when I try to get count value from one column, I get the number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd

def get_count_RS_Tier(filepath, column1, word):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    sec = df[column1].str.count(word).sum()
    print(sec)

    first = df.RS[df.Status == "Paid"]
    print(first.describe())

get_count_RS_Tier("Enterprise")
```

the value for sec is 878, which is the correct value. But when I try to filter by a string value, I am getting an empty dataframe.

I need a way to get the count value of cells by multiple filters.

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:

So, everytime I try filter the dataframe,

```
sec1 = df.RS_Tier == "Enterprise"
sec2 = df.INV_Status == "Paid in Full"
first = df[sec1]
print(first.head())
```

The return value is an Empty Dataframe. I don't understand how this can be possible.

EDIT2:

[image]

So, I would like to get the integer value based on if (Saas) and (Paid) for (SMB)

So, if I wanted to find the number of Saas that were paid in SMB, the output would hopefully be 1.

Comment: Please include code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. Also I strongly suggest not to use `.`-style column indexing, in favour of `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You havent given us a lot to work with. But maybe you just need to do

```
first = df[df.Status == "Paid"].RS
```

Instead.

Comment: @B_working_K_hard, a minimal sample of df where the problem can be observed, and expected output would help a lot.

Comment: hey. I added an example of the dataframe I am working with.